# Teradata SQL syntax from date to quarter

Tags: syntax, date, teradata

I need Teradata SQL syntax to extract quarter from a date:

```
Date: (YYYY-MM-DD)
2015-09-12
2015-05-22
2014-12-15
```

Given below is the expected output:

```
3Q15
2Q15
4Q14
```

Query which I have tried (wrapped for readability):

```
SELECT DATE, ((CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) AS BYTEINT)-1)/3)+1 
    || 'Q' || substring(DATE,3,2) quarter
```

Error:

> Missing parameters

Answer (score 3):

Teradata supports Oracle's `TO_CHAR` syntax since TD14:

```
TO_CHAR(date, 'q"Q"yy')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sel curr_payment_quarter, 
    ((CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM curr_payment_DATE) AS BYTEINT)-1)/3)+1 
    || 'Q' || substring(curr_payment_quarter,3,2)  as quarter,
    curr_payment_DATE
from PAYMENT_DETAILS
```

To be clear, Teradata supports `sel` as a shortcut for `select`